# How to send a like to facebook from delphi?

Tags: facebook, delphi, hyperlink, facebook-like

In my app I have a small custom button that just shows an FB icon and links to the business page.  I want to have the button perform a Like so that my Like number on the page increases.

So far I only see a way to fetch the Like graphic from FB with a link there to like it.  How do I skip right to the Like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your user needs to go to a page on facebook so that facebook can confirm their account and their intention to "like".  You can't get around this - it's by design so that spammy applications can't force users to "like" against their wishes.

Comment: I see!  Well I don't want to be spammy, just efficient :)  I will abandon that line of thought.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you:

> https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=33184
>
> http://code.google.com/p/delphibook/
>
> http://[REDACTED]

Comment: I like the third link ;)

Comment: @ServerOverflow omg, thanks for letting me know. I've removed it.

Comment: Probably the owner of the domain let the domain expire, and some very enterprising guy bought it and reused it for commercial purposes. Conclusion: never let your domains expire :)